# Ошибка 127 в github actions

Tags: github, github-actions

Что я делаю не так? Мой код в Github actions выводит ошибку, хотя все сделано точно по тутору (https://habr.com/ru/post/476368/)

```
on: [push]
jobs:
   run_tests:
     runs-on: [ubuntu-latest]
     steps:
       - uses: actions/checkout@master
       - uses: actions/setup-python@v1
         with:
           python-version: '3.8'
           architecture: 'x64'
       - name: Install requirements
         run: pip install -r requirements.txt
       - name: Run tests
         run: coverage run -m src/tests.py
       - name: Tests report
         run: coverage report
```

Код ошибки:

```
coverage run -m src/tests.py
shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
env:
  pythonLocation: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.14/x64
/home/runner/work/_temp/41a32481-9d09-44c6-9784-55b0d5a24d4c.sh: line 1: coverage: 
command not found
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.
```

Comment: Ну видимо вы забыли прописать coverage в зависимости своего проекта

Comment: coverage имеет смысл либо отдельно ставить, прямо в конфиге github actions через pip install, либо хранить в отдельном файле зависимостей (нужных только во время разработки/тестирования).